# What are the minimum system requirements for ultimate edition 4.2

Tags: linux

I was choosing a Linux edition to install in my PC. I have an Intel pentium dual core with 2.9 processor speed and 2GB Ram. Now running just XP on it.

I found the Ultimate edition 4.2.1, so can I install this version in my pc? what are the minimum system requirements to install this version? Is there is any cons of this version?

I couldn’t really find a website to see the minimum system required to install each Linux version. If there are any sort of sites please help me with the link. :-)

Are all versions/distributions of Linux able to dual boot?

Comment: The OS will just run fine. I assume you also want to play games when you install this kind of distro, so that depends a lot on your graphics card and the requirements of the game. In this sense, the question is not really answerable for us.

Comment: Dual booting is possible with all Linux  distributions, but some make it easier to set up during install. What you should do in the beginning is using a *Live USB Drive* (i.e. booting the distro from a USB drive without modifying your system at all). That way, you can test the distribution and get familiar with the look and feel.

Comment: Running XP on bare metal is playing Russian roulette, certainly now that it is no longer maintained